# Unicode path problem with building qt quick project

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, makefile, qml

i have a problem with building a qt quick project inside a path contains unicode characters.

i have 4 files:

- CMakeLists.txt
- main.cpp
- main.qml
- FramedImage.qml

the content of CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)


set(PROJECT_NAME QMLFO)
project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ../)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Quick Gui REQUIRED)

qt_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::Gui Qt6::Quick)

qt6_add_qml_module(${PROJECT_NAME}
    URI hello
    VERSION 2.0
    QML_FILES main.qml FramedImage.qml)
```

when i try to build into a directory called **مرحبا**,

--

the following error occurs

```
[  9%] Built target QMLFO_tooling
[ 13%] Running qmlimportscanner for QMLFO
The system cannot find the path specified.
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\QMLFO_qmlimportscan.dir\build.make:76: .qt_plugins/Qt6_QmlPlugins_Imports_QMLFO.cmake] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:384: CMakeFiles/QMLFO_qmlimportscan.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2
```

however,the generation stage is completed successfully without problems.

i thought the problem was with the build tool,but that wasn't the case(by the way,i use mingw32-make).
when i use the build tool seperatly,it can compile into a unicode path without a problem.